# How do I take a rough polygon and make it a bezier curve with the Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, polygon, bezier

Let's say I have an array of LatLng points which make up a polygon.  Is there anyway to smooth it out to look more curve like.

I imagine it would require some kind of processing to insert points into the array with some some sort of threshold to prevent the points from getting too numerous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you could do is use the curve to draw the curve between each of your LatLng points. There isn't a built in algorithm to add in points etc. You would have to do that on the backend yourself.

Somebody else may have already done it themselves on the backend so I would suggest doing a search before reinventing the wheel yourself.

Sorry its the really the answer you were looking for....

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that I couldn't find it in my searches, and it's not worth the time at the moment to try and translate C code (the only thing I could find relating to curves) into JS to do this.

Comment: You could still use the C and do it on the backend.